# Adagrad implicit variables

Tags: variables, tensorflow, implicit, tensorboard

The following model:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

BATCH_SIZE = 3
VECTOR_SIZE = 1
LEARNING_RATE = 0.1

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='input_placeholder')
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE],
                   name='labels_placeholder')

W = tf.get_variable('W', [VECTOR_SIZE, BATCH_SIZE])
b = tf.get_variable('b', [VECTOR_SIZE], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))

y_hat = tf.matmul(W, x) + b
predict = tf.add(tf.matmul(W, x), b, name='predict')
total_loss = tf.reduce_mean(y-y_hat, name='total_loss')
train_step = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(LEARNING_RATE).minimize(total_loss)
X = np.ones([BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE])
Y = np.ones([BATCH_SIZE, VECTOR_SIZE])
all_saver = tf.train.Saver()
```

Has the following list of variables:

```py
for el in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES):
    print(el)


<tf.Variable 'W:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'b:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'W/Adagrad:0' shape=(1, 3) dtype=float32_ref>
<tf.Variable 'b/Adagrad:0' shape=(1,) dtype=float32_ref>
```

Tensors `W:0` and `b:0` are obvious ones, but where `W/Adagrad:0` and `b/Adagrad:0` are coming from is not completely clear. I also do not see them on tensorboard:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those Variables are defined in the moment you call the `AdagradOptimizer`. All the optimisers use a certain number of variables to store values they need in doing their job.

For what concerns Adagrad, let me remember what a standard gradient descent update step looks like:

```
  theta(t+1) = theta(t) - eta * grad_theta(t)
```

where `theta` is a generic parameter (like your `W` or `b`), `eta` is a constant learning rate and `grad_theta` is the gradient of your loss function w.r.t. `theta` at iteration `t`.

Often, people use a particular scheduling for the learning rate `eta` because they need a larger `eta` in the initial phase of learning, while a smaller `eta` in the final phase (when you are very close to the minimum and you want to avoid oscillating around it). Adagrad tries to do it automatically using the following idea: "I store the square root of gradients of `theta` up to iteration `t` and I scale `eta` proportionally". In other words, given:

```
adagrad_theta(t) = sum(grad_theta(tau)) for tau=1,.., t
```

the update rule of Adagrad id the following:

```
theta(t+1) = theta(t) - eta * grad_theta(t)/(sqrt(adagrad_theta(t)+ eps))
```

As you can see, the learning rate is rescaled w.r.t. the `adagrad_theta` value. Here, `eps` is a small constant (e.g. 1e-12) for avoiding division by zero. Another characteristic of this update rule is that the more you update a parameter up to a certain point, the less you will do in the following steps.

`W/Adagrad:0` and `b/Adagrad:0` are nothing more than the `adagrad_theta` for your variables `W` and `b`, respectively. There the sum of the gradients of these variables get accumulated.

Tensorboard knows they are particular Variables (related not to the model but to the optimization strategy) and then do not attach them to your actual graph. However, you are still capable of seeing them in the upper right of the screen. If you want to see them in your current graph just click on them and, in your upper right corner, you have the option to attach them to your graph.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I understand why Tensorflow needs to store `W` and `b`, but what is the point in storing Hessian?

Comment: I was generic in that answer. Adagrad is quite simple optimization algorithm. I edit the answer and try to explain you